# Problem Dual Booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu - Windows Not Loading

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Kindly advise on this challenge. First off, I have read all the other similar problems here but I couldn't find the solution to my issue.

I installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on a Dell Inspirion 7537. I first restored the system to Factory Settings then installed Ubuntu. The screenshot of the Grub Options are as below:

[Grub Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5VHGL.png)
... Windows is not loading.

However, if I press F12 as the device is starting up, I see Windows as an Option: [Boot Options - F12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fsm0Q.jpg).

From the foregoing, what have I done wrong? What are the possible solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ Windows is installed in UEFI boot mode, but do not see the Ubuntu entry in UEFI boot mode. UEFI & BIOS/CSM/Legacy are not compatible. Or grub will only boot other systems installed in same boot mode. If Ubuntu in BIOS mode, Boot-Repair's advanced options if in UEFI mode can fix.

Comment: @oldfred: I have done as advised. The Boot-REpair report is at this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25950307/. Please note that Grub now comes up on start up but Windows 10 is still not listed in the options. Thank you.

Comment: You have mixed UEFI & BIOS. They are not compatible and once you start booting in one mode you cannot switch. Or grub will only offer to boot other systems installed in same boot mode. You can leave as is, but may have to turn on/off UEFI or CSM/Legacy mode and can only directly boot from UEFI boot menu. Or you can use Boot-Repair advanced settings in UEFI boot mode and uninstall grub-pc(BIOS) and install grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot.

Comment: **Or you can use Boot-Repair advanced settings in UEFI boot mode and uninstall grub-pc(BIOS) and install grub-efi-amd64 for UEFI boot.**

Kindly share the steps/command for this if it won't be too much of a bother. Thank you.

Comment: See this as posted above, it shows screens: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ choose the purge & reinstall grub option. You may want to update kernel also. But be sure to boot Ubuntu in UEFI mode and then add ppa for Boot-Repair.